# How to interpret null-coalescing operators in c#

Tags: c#, null, nullable

I have been given some code using nullable types, which are new to me (I learnt C# many years ago, in its infancy, and haven't kept up, sorry!)

The code I am trying to understand is

```
public readonly Trie?[] next = new Trie?[26];
```

and

```
var t = next[u] ??= new Trie();
t.insert(p[1..]);
```

To understand what's going on here, I have tried to rewrite this as

```
    if (next is null)
    {
         var t = new Trie();
         t.insert(p[1..]);
    }
    else
    {
         var t = next[u];

         if (t is null)
               t = new Trie();

         t.insert(p[1..]);
     }
```

but it doesn't return the same results when the code is run.

Question 1: is it possible to rewrite this nullable syntax in 'old-school' C#?

Question 2: if so, what's wrong with my interpretation?

If I can answer these, I will be able to start using these types in my own code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For given fragment

```
var t = next[u] ??= new Trie();
t.insert(p[1..]);
```

let's add parenthesis:

```
// check if next[u] is null and if it is, 
// create and assign new instance of Trie to it 
var t = (next[u] ??= new Trie());

t.insert(p[1..]);
```

Then we can translate it int good old style as

```
if (next[u] == null) 
  next[u] = new Trie();

var t = next[u];

t.insert(p[1..]);
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what the OP wrote would correspond to `var t = next[u] ?? new Trie();` rather than `var t = next[u] ??= new Trie();`, i.e. they specifically missed the assignment. What you're saying is obviously true but just pointing out why what they did was wrong.

Comment: Thank you; the addition of the brackets made it so much more obvious. I'm still unsure though why this tendency to write ever more terse code. Does it really help? I prefer the old-style method!